# Create record causes org.hibernate.MappingException: Unknown entity

Tags: java, database, hibernate, jdbc

I am trying to create a record in a table but it gives me the following exception.

```
org.hibernate.MappingException: Unknown entity: com.Person
```

My `get(Person person)` method works fine and returns the result.

**DAO class:**

```
public void create(Person person){
    Session session = HibernateUtil.getSession();
    Transaction tx = session.beginTransaction();

    session.save(person);//----------------------->this throws exception
    session.flush();
    tx.commit();
    session.close();
}

public List<Person> get(Person person){
    criteria = createCriteria("person");
    criteria.add(Restrictions.eq("person", person.getFirstName()));
    return criteria.list();     
}
```

**hibernate.cfg.xml file:**

```
<hibernate-configuration>
    <session-factory>
        //other database properties
        <mapping resource="com/Person.hbm.xml" />
    </session-factory>
</hibernate-configuration>
```

**Person.hbm.xml file:**

```
<hibernate-mapping default-lazy="false">
    <class name="com.Person" table="Person" entity-name="person">
        <id name="personId" type="integer" column="PERSON_ID">
            <generator class="increment"/>
        </id>
        <property name="firstName" column="FIRST_NAME"/>
        <property name="address" column="ADDRESS"/>
    </class>   
</hibernate-mapping>
```

**Entity mapped to table Person:**

```
public class Person implements Serializable{
    private Integer personId;
    private String firstName;
    private String address;

    public Person(){}

    //getters setters
}
```

Comment: So what package is your `Person` class in?

Comment: @DavidWallace my Person class and its hbm file are in different package. Could this cause a problem? But my get() works fine.

Comment: It doesn't matter where you put your HBM file, so long as Hibernate can find it.  But your HBM file says that your `Person` class is in a package called `com`.  That's OK if that's really where it is; it just seemed a bit odd to me to have it there.

Comment: Calling session.get() on an unmapped class will not throw an error like you'd expect (I wished it did).  It will return null.  When you call save() on an unmapped class you will get an error. So your hibernate configuration is not getting picked up like you expect.  Could you post the code where you create your Hibernate SessionFactory.

Comment: @DavidWallace I just shortened the package name for simplicity. Thank you.

Comment: Yeah, you need to give the full, correct package name in the HBM file.  Hibernate doesn't like simplicity.

Comment: @DavidWallace My actual hbm file has the full package name. I just shortened it for the forum to keep it simple.

Comment: Oh, I see.  Sorry for misunderstanding you.  Well, then, I can't see why you'd get that error.  Have you tried debugging within the Hibernate source?

Comment: @neildo I don't have access to the details of the code that creates the session. But the fact that my get() method returns results, doesn't that mean that hiberante sees my configuration file?

Comment: @DavidWallace I haven't. I will try debugging through the hibernate source. thanks

Comment: OK, I guess I misunderstood what you meant by your get method working.  If you are saying that it returns actual results, not just null, then yes, that should mean Hibernate is configured properly.  Can you post the code for your createCriteria method?  It seems like the way you are obtaining your Session in your save method does not match the createCriteria method.

Comment: @neildo createCriteria method obtains the session in the same way as my create() method.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue is caused by using the entity-name property in your hbm.xml file.  If you do this then you must also provide the same entity-name when you call save:

```
session.save("person", person);
```

A cleaner option would be to remove the entity-name property from your mapping file so you can just call save(person) w/o having to provide an entity-name (it defaults to the FQ class name).  Then create your criteria by passing the class instead of a string name.  For example:

```
session.createCriteria(Person.class);
```